# How to get the value from a Scott encoded GADT with type equality constraints?

Tags: haskell, gadt, continuation-passing, refinements, refinement-type

I am reading [the Rank-N-Types section of 24 days of GHC Extensions](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html) and came across the following GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Char

data Some :: * -> * where
    SomeInt  :: Int -> Some Int
    SomeChar :: Char -> Some Char
    Anything :: a -> Some a

unSome :: Some a -> a
unSome (SomeInt x) = x + 3
unSome (SomeChar c) = toLower c
unSome (Anything x) = x

unSome (someInt 2) -- 5
```

Although `unSome` is polymorphic in its type variables one can give the compiler proof that in the `SomeInt` case for instance, it is safe to add three to the given value. The author calls this type refinement.

Now I was curious whether I can do the same with a Scrott encoded type. Fortunately, there is an example of such encoding. We merely need the Rank-N-Types and Type-Families extensions turned on:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype SomeC a =
    SomeC {
      runSomeC ::
          forall r.
          ((a ~ Int) => Int -> r) ->
          ((a ~ Char) => Char -> r) ->
          (a -> r) ->
          r
    }
```

However, `unSome` isn't provided in the article. I am not well-versed in Haskell and don't have a clue how to implement this function with Scott encoding. Especially the type equality constraints (e.g. `(a ~ Int) =>`) confuse me.

Any help or information on other online sources are appreciated.

Comment: Same exact way you do it with any other CPS encoded datatype ('Scrott'?) - pass the function corresponding to each case as input to the elimination function. You can write an equivalent `unSome` as `\k -> runSomeC k (+3) toUpper id`.

Comment: @user2407038 But where is the magic introduced by `(a ~ Int) =>`, then? Sorry, I really don't understand what this constraint is actually doing.

Comment: @ftor Note that the user of a `SomeC a` may choose `r` to be a type that mentions `a`; e.g. they will choose `r ~ a` when writing `unSome`. Then together with `a ~ Int` that would mean they can get an `Int` out of the `Int -> r` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use the provided function to replace your pattern match, as in:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Char

newtype SomeC a =
    SomeC {
      runSomeC ::
          forall r.
          ((a ~ Int) => Int -> r) ->
          ((a ~ Char) => Char -> r) ->
          (a -> r) ->
          r
    }

unSome :: SomeC a -> a
unSome (SomeC f) = f (\x -> x+3) (\c -> toLower c) (\x -> x)
```

In ghci:

```
> unSome (SomeC (\someInt someChar anything -> someInt 2))
5
```

Comment: So it's that simple! The difficulty is obviously more in the definition of the type than in its implementation.

Comment: So `(a ~ Char) =>` isn't an implicit function.  What is it then? Just an assertion of equality?

Comment: `((a ~ Char) => a -> r) -> r` means "given a function which may assume that `a` is `Char` and takes as input `a` and produces as output `r`, produce as output `r`". It's just a constraint - same as e.g. `(Show a => a -> r) -> r`.

Comment: @ftor Yes, it is an assertion of equality. The assertion is checked at compile time, and can be used at compile time to convert terms that are apparently of a type mentioning one side of the equation to terms of a type mentioning the other side. Depending on how far you want to move from "denotational semantics" to "how the implementation of those semantics works"... in GHC it is *also* an implicit function which takes as an argument evidence that the one type is equal to the other, in the form of a coercion that the compiler can emit when converting terms from one type to the other.

Comment: That means I cannot assert that `a` is an odd integer for instance, because the compiler can't determine this at compile time?

Comment: @ftor `a` is definitely not an odd integer; it is a type. Integers are values. If you had a type whose inhabitants were odd integers, you could assert that `a` was that type.

Comment: Yes, of course. Confusion again, sorry. I just though the example above would lead to type families and dependent types. I really have a hard time understanding them. Thanks for your help!